# When to tell if a continuous sporadic stream of floats crosses an integer?

Tags: c#, math, floating-point, integer

Suppose in an Update loop that updates at variable frame rates, you receive a continuous stream of floats - usually increasing steadily except when it changes direction and decreases (also steadily).

How do you detect when a particular loop has hit or crossed an integer (exactly)?

(The implementation does not have to be C# specific, but that is just what I am using to implement... so if there are any C# methods that help, that would be cool too!)

Basically, how do you make this more performant:

```
           int floor0 = Mathf.FloorToInt(lastTH);
            int ceil0 = Mathf.CeilToInt(lastTH);
            float delta = th - lastTH;
            if (delta > 0)
            {
                // increasing
                if (ceil0 > th) Hit();
            }
            else
            {
                // decreasing
                if (floor0 < th) Hit();
            }

lastTH = th;
```

Comment: In crude sense :- If stream is: 0.245, 1.12, 5.00, 0.2589
You want to know when we point at 5 => Integer?

Comment: no, i mean when it crosses even if it does not hit 5.00 per se. So in your numbers, i'd like to know when it hits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

Answer (score 1):

If the stream has just increased, x is the previous value, and y is the new value, then there is an integer greater than x and less than or equal to y iff x < floor(y).

If the stream has just decreased, there is an integer less than x and greater than or equal to y iff x > ceil(y).

These can be combined without needing to ascertain direction; there is an integer at y (but x ≠ y) or between x and y iff x < floor(y) or x > ceil(y).

Comment: Why is the stream-independent algorithm asymmetrical?

Comment: @ina: It is not asymmetric. −ceil(y) = floor(−y), so x > ceil(y) is equivalent to −x < floor(−y).

Answer (score 0):

A particular loop, and a particular point?  Well, allowing for floating-point fuzziness, how about this? *(pseudocode ...)*

```
var less_found = false;
var geq_found  = false;

while (your_loop) {
  ...
  if (value <  threshold) less_found = true;
  if (value >= threshold) geq_found  = true;
  ...
}
```

At the end of the loop, check the flags.

If the values are floats, then I recommend that `threshold` should be a float also.

Comment: Now – this is just one possible interpretation of your somewhat-ambiguous question ...

Comment: how do you determine what the threshhold is though?